# Распаковка значений объекта

Tags: python

На каждой итерации приходит список из 2-х переменных, требуется сразу распаковывать в 2 переменные: for product, cost in shop.
Как это сделать?

```
shop = [['каретка', 1200], ['шатун', 1000], ['седло', 300],
        ['педаль', 100], ['седло', 1500], ['рама', 12000],
        ['обод', 2000], ['шатун', 200], ['седло', 2700]]

det_count = 0
det_cost = 0
detail = input('Название детали: ')

for i in range(len(shop)):
    if shop[i][0] == detail.lower():
        det_count += 1
        det_cost += shop[i][1]
print()
if det_count > 0:
    print('Кол-во деталей -', det_count)
    print('Общая стоимость -', det_cost)
else:
    print('Товар не найден.')
```

Comment: Переделайте shop в словарь

Answer (score 1):

Переделайте объект `shop` в словарь вида
`shop = {'каретка' : 1200, ...}`, после чего для распаковки элементов словаря можно использовать следующую конструкцию:

```
for product, cost in shop.items()
```

Но конкретно для вашей задачи для того, чтобы получить стоимость детали по названию достаточно будет сделать следующее:

```
detail = input().lower()
if detail in shop:
    cost += shop[detail]
```

Если вы не знакомы с такой структурой данных как словарь, то советую почитать [официальную документацию](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries)

Comment: `после чего используйте следующую конструкцию` после чего эта конструкция не нужна

Comment: @MBo да, для его кода она в принципе не пригодится, но в формулировке вопроса изначально было желание именно распаковать переменные из объектов такого типа, я лишь продемонстрировал ему как это можно сделать

Comment: Так если же вы показываете, как изменить неудачную структуру данных,  то и применение новой структуры лучше продемонстрировать правильно, а не приспосабливать то, как было со старой.

Comment: @MBo учту на будущее и  дополню ответ, спасибо.

Comment: Вот теперь хорошо ;) +

Answer (score 0):

> требуется сразу распаковывать в 2 переменные: `for product, cost in shop`

Ну, именно так и напишите, только двоеточие нужно добавить в конце:

```
for product, cost in shop:
    if product == detail.lower():
        det_count += 1
        det_cost += cost
```